# Getting Invariant Violation with React Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

The following code is giving me an `Uncaught Invariant Violation`. I have no idea why. It's copied almost exactly from the Bootstrap example.

`Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of 'LoginForm'.`

```
import React from 'react';
import { FormGroup, ControlLabel, FormControl, HelpBlock, Button } from 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

const FieldGroup = ({ id, label, help, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <FormGroup controlId={id}>
      <ControlLabel>{label}</ControlLabel>
      <FormControl {...props} />
      {help && <HelpBlock>{help}</HelpBlock>}
    </FormGroup>
  );
};

const LoginForm = props => {
  return (
    <form>
      <FieldGroup
        id="loginText"
        type="text"
        label="Text"
        placeholder="Email"
      />
      <FieldGroup
        id="loginPassword"
        label="Password"
        type="password"
      />
      <Button type="submit">
        Login
      </Button>
    </form>
  );
};

export const LoginCtrl = props => {
  return (<LoginForm/>);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import those components from `react-boostrap`, the actual package that defines them, not from the .css file - that doesn't have any React components, just styles (that's why you're getting undefineds).

```
import { FormGroup, ControlLabel, FormControl, HelpBlock, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
```

Comment: Depends on your build setup, specifically if you're using WebPack with css-loader or something similar, it won't throw, since the .css file is not a javascript module. It's something else, that is handled by a particular loader.